# Joining two DateTime's and getting the number of ticks

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm retrieving records from a database and it has two columns. One for Date and one for Time.

Date looks like this: `19/05/2011 00:00:00` and Time looks like this: `01/01/1900 15:28:00` which is fine, I can combine them easily with `Date.Add(Time.TimeOfDay`) and that gives me `19/05/2011 15:28:00`.

If I try and get the "ticks" from that DateTime stamp with `CombinedDateTime.Ticks` it gives me the wrong one, e.g. `6344141544100000000` - it's like it's not finding the time. If I print the DateTime out it does show with the time and everything looks okay.

```
Date = new DateTime(2010, 05, 19);
Time = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01, 15, 45, 00);
Combined = Date.Add(Time.TimeOfDay);
// Combined.ToString() prints the expected 19/05/2011 15:45:00
// Combined.Ticks gives an invalid "tick count", e.g 6344141544100000000
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: how can you represent "00/00/0000 15:28:00" with `DateTime`? I tried `DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(0, 0, 0, 15, 28, 0, 0);` and I got a runtime exception 'Unrepresentable' .

Comment: @Bala @SLaks I've just edited my post. I mean 01/01/1900 :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding `Ticks`.

[`Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) is a measured in units of **100 nanoseconds** each; there are 10,000,000 ticks in a second.

There will *always* be zeroes at the end, unless your time as a fractional number of microseconds.

Comment: I'm an idiot, you're correct. I guess my question has changed, should I create another or ask it here? `var TS = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - CombinedDateTime.Ticks);` and `TS.TotalSeconds` is always -3600..

Comment: @eth: First of all, `var ts = DateTime.UtcNow - CombinedDateTime;`

Comment: It was a problem with DateTime.UtcNow for some reason, DateTime.Now works perfectly - weird. Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is immutable, when you invoke Add it creates a new DateTime instance. Are you invoking Ticks on the original DateTime?

Comment: `CombinedDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("19/05/2011 15:39:30")`

Shouldn't `CombinedDateTime.Ticks` return the correct ammount of ticks? Again, it returns a load of zeros at the end...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're updating your object when you combine them

```
Date = Date.Add(Time.TimeOfDay)

Date.Ticks;
```